# Application Insights telemetry correlation using log4net

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I'm looking to have our distributed event logging have proper correlation. For our Web Applications this seems to be automatic. Example of correlated logs from one of our App Services API:

[image]

However, for our other (non ASP, non WebApp) services were we use Log4Net and the App Insights appender our logs are not correlated. I tried following instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation

Even after adding unique operation_Id attributes to each operation, we're not seeing log correlation (I also tried "Operation Id"). Example of none correlated log entry:
[image]

Any help on how to achieve this using log4net would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Across services correlation IDs are mostly propagated through headers. When AI is enabled for Web Application, it reads IDs/Context from the incoming headers and then updates outgoing headers with the appropriate IDs/Context. Within service, operation is tracked with Activity object and every telemetry emitted will be associated with this Activity, thus sharing necessary correlation IDs.

In case of Service Bus / Event Hub communication, the propagation [is also supported in the recent versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing) (IDs/Context propagate as metadata).

If service is not web-based and AI automated correlation propagation is not working, [you may need to manually get incoming ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking) information from some metadata if any exists, restore/initiate Activity, start AI operation with this Activity. When telemetry item is generated in scope of that Activity, it will get proper IDs and will be part of the overarching trace. With that, if telemetry is generated from Log4net trace that was executed in the scope of AI operation context then that telemetry should get right IDs.

[Code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking#http-request-in-owin-self-hosted-app) to access correlation from headers:

```
public class ApplicationInsightsMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    // you may create a new TelemetryConfiguration instance, reuse one you already have
    // or fetch the instance created by Application Insights SDK.
    private readonly TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);

    public ApplicationInsightsMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) {}

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        // Let's create and start RequestTelemetry.
        var requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry
        {
            Name = $"{context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)}"
        };

        // If there is a Request-Id received from the upstream service, set the telemetry context accordingly.
        if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Request-Id"))
        {
            var requestId = context.Request.Headers.Get("Request-Id");
            // Get the operation ID from the Request-Id (if you follow the HTTP Protocol for Correlation).
            requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.Id = GetOperationId(requestId);
            requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.ParentId = requestId;
        }

        // StartOperation is a helper method that allows correlation of 
        // current operations with nested operations/telemetry
        // and initializes start time and duration on telemetry items.
        var operation = telemetryClient.StartOperation(requestTelemetry);

        // Process the request.
        try
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            requestTelemetry.Success = false;
            telemetryClient.TrackException(e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Update status code and success as appropriate.
            if (context.Response != null)
            {
                requestTelemetry.ResponseCode = context.Response.StatusCode.ToString();
                requestTelemetry.Success = context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode <= 299;
            }
            else
            {
                requestTelemetry.Success = false;
            }

            // Now it's time to stop the operation (and track telemetry).
            telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
        }
    }

    public static string GetOperationId(string id)
    {
        // Returns the root ID from the '|' to the first '.' if any.
        int rootEnd = id.IndexOf('.');
        if (rootEnd < 0)
            rootEnd = id.Length;

        int rootStart = id[0] == '|' ? 1 : 0;
        return id.Substring(rootStart, rootEnd - rootStart);
    }
}
```

[Code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking#long-running-background-tasks) for manual correlated operation tracking in isolation:

```
async Task BackgroundTask()
{
    var operation = telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>(taskName);
    operation.Telemetry.Type = "Background";
    try
    {
        int progress = 0;
        while (progress < 100)
        {
            // Process the task.
            telemetryClient.TrackTrace($"done {progress++}%");
        }
        // Update status code and success as appropriate.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackException(e);
        // Update status code and success as appropriate.
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
    }
}
```

Please note that the most recent version of Application Insights SDK is switching to W3C correlation standard, so header names and expected format would be different [as per W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/).

Comment: I'll give this a go and report back - thanks for the detailed reply!